# AWTAutoShutdown thread halting VM

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a legacy project where someone had used swing timer threads to do some server scheduling tasks. This code is not a swing app, it's server side java. I know this is not a good idea, and know acceptable ways to do the same. The question is, I see some long VM pauses that happen every several minutes under no load. Enabling verbose gc, I determined it's not garbage collection. When I do a thread dump during one of those pauses, I get this dump below. Any idea if this AWTAutoShutdown could be causing this pause, or what it's doing when it does this activateBlockerThread shown below?

```
"AWT-Shutdown" prio=10 tid=0x00007fed5802d000 nid=0x2ef1 in Object.wait() [0x00007fed53e5d000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x000000031e910b90> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.run(Unknown Source)
- locked <0x000000031e910b90> (a java.lang.Object)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

"TimerQueue" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fed58597000 nid=0x2a56 in Object.wait() [0x00007fed54737000]
java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
   - waiting on <0x000000031e910b90> (a java.lang.Object)
   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
   at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.activateBlockerThread(Unknown Source)
   at sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown.notifyThreadBusy(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x000000031e910b90> (a java.lang.Object)
   - locked <0x000000031e9a60c8> (a java.lang.Object)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.postEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.postEventPrivate(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x000000031e90eb90> (a java.awt.EventQueue)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.postEvent(Unknown Source)
   at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.Timer$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at javax.swing.Timer$1.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at javax.swing.Timer.post(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x000000031e9af7e0> (a javax.swing.Timer)
   at javax.swing.TimerQueue.postExpiredTimers(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x000000031e90ce60> (a javax.swing.TimerQueue)
   at javax.swing.TimerQueue.run(Unknown Source)
   - locked <0x000000031e90ce60> (a javax.swing.TimerQueue)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: what is a "vm pause under no load"?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your question, so thought I'd answer for completeness sake, but we see a timer thread's log message fire at it's scheduled interval. But every several minutes, it pauses for up to 30 seconds. We seem to have identified the VM Thread as taking up the majority of the cpu also, during this pause. But running verbose gc, we do not see any gc activity during that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may be having issues with notification.  The TimerQueue thread should have woken up after the AWT-Shutdown thread got started (the AWTAutShutdown.run method signals the monitor that the AWTAutShutdown.activateBlockerThread method is waiting on).  if your app is freezing for an extended time and these threads aren't making progress, it would seem that the TimerQueue thread is not receiving the signal in a timely manner.

However, seeing as you application is *not* a swing/awt application, i don't see how this would affect anything else in the application.

Comment: The Timer is being constructed with an ActionListener, and if that listener's actionPerformed method takes a long time to complete when it's called, that would cause them to back up?

Comment: @AlperAkture - yes, the swing timers all execute on the same thread, so one long task will block all the others.

Comment: We're watching a log message from one of the timers. It outputs every three seconds, but will stop periodically for up to 30 seconds. So it must backed up by some other Timer executing as you say. The thread we think we identified as occupying the CPU (using top and the thread id) seems to be: "VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00000000415ff000 nid=0x2a16 runnable, which doesn't have a trace. But I think you answered my question, thanks!